# How to query the nearest neighbors including the ones at distance zero with Scipy's cKDTree?

Tags: python, scipy

I want to find the neighbors within a distance using Scipy cKDTree. Most important, I want the point itself (zero distance) as well. cKDTree. query gives all the neighbors but without zero distance.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you give more details on your code and how you are querying your tree ? I am not sure to see your issue. If you build a tree like `tree = cKDTree(ref_points)` and query it with something like `_, idx = tree.query(other_points, k=3)` the `idx ` variable will contain, for each point of `other_points`, the id of the 3 nearest in `ref_points` including if one of these indexed point have the same coordinates (ie zero distance) of the queried point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In a list [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], I want to find neighbors of point [5] within a distance of 2. cKDTree gives me points [3, 4, 6, 7]. But I want [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]. Does this clarify my question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't really reproduce your issue (or it might depends on the method that you are using to query the tree).

Considering this simple snippet of code :

```
>>> from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
>>> import numpy as np

>>> points_ref = np.array([(1, 1), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 4), (6, 6)])
>>> tree = cKDTree(points_ref)
```

Querying for the nearest neighbors at a distance of `2` around the point `(4, 4)` with the method [`cKDTree.query_ball_point`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_ball_point.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_ball_point) can give something like :

```
>>> idx = tree.query_ball_point((4, 4), 2)
>>> points_ref[idx]
# array([[3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 4]])
```

Which returns the point with a distance of 0.

Querying for the *n-nearest* neighbors with the method [`cKDTree.query`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query) also seems to return the point with a distance of 0 :

```
>>> _, idx = tree.query((3, 3), k=2)
>>> points_ref[idx]
# array([[3, 3], [4, 4]])
```